# Nested REST call in REST-datasource bound Listview

Tags: html, rest, xmlhttprequest, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a Windows 8 JavaScript application, in which I am binding a VirtualDataSource retrieving products from a RESTful service to a Listview.

//fetch data as user scrolls
itemsFromIndex: function (requestIndex, countBefore, countAfter) {

```
           return WinJS.xhr(options).then(
                //Callback for success
                function (request) {
                    var results = [], count;
                    console.log("request.responseText: " + request.responseText);
                    // Use the JSON parser on the results, safer than eval
                    var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                    console.log("obj: " + obj);

                    // Verify if the service has returned images
                    if (obj.length > 0) {
                        var items = obj;
                        console.log("returned items: " + items.length);
                        console.log("returned items: " +items[0].productid);
                        // Data adapter results needs an array of items of the shape:
                        // items =[{ key: key1, data : { field1: value, field2: value, ... }}, { key: key2, data : {...}}, ...];
                        // Form the array of results objects
                        for (var i = 0, itemsLength = items.length; i < itemsLength; i++) {
                            var dataItem = items[i];
                            var text = "aaa";
                            **var a = fetchPrice(dataItem.productid);**
                            console.log("shortText = " + a.text);
                            results.push({
                                key: (fetchIndex + i).toString(),
                                data: {
                                    productId: dataItem.productid,
                                    price: a
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

so far so good... now for the trouble... once I have retrieved all products, I need to display e.g. the price of a product by calling another webservice, but within the same listview template.
What is the best way of going about this? As you may see, I already added code like fetchPrice, which is another WinJS.xhr call. Is there a better way of doing this? Can I bind a price html-element to a productid which will only become available at runtime?

Please help!

Thanks,
Thomas

--

Actually got a bit further now:

```
                    var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                    console.log("obj: " + obj);

                    // Verify if the service has returned images
                    if (obj.length > 0) {
                        var items = obj;
                        console.log("returned items: " + items.length);
                        console.log("returned items: " + items[0].productid);
                        var priceText;
                        that.getPriceText(items[0].productid).done(function (b) { priceText = b; console.log("in function : " + priceText); });
                        console.log("priceText is " + priceText);
                        // console.log("var b = " + b.isPrototypeOf);
                        // Data adapter results needs an array of items of the shape:
                        // items =[{ key: key1, data : { field1: value, field2: value, ... }}, { key: key2, data : {...}}, ...];
                        // Form the array of results objects
                        for (var i = 0, itemsLength = items.length; i < itemsLength; i++) {
                            var dataItem = items[i];

                            results.push({
                                key: (fetchIndex + i).toString(),
                                data: {
                                    productId: dataItem.productid,
                                    price: priceText
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

The console output of the second line saying console.log (console.log("priceTextis " + priceText)) returns undefined: this is expected, as the priceText async call has not yet finished.

The priceText output within the .done function of the async call is output to the console correctly. (Line reading ("in function : " etc.)

How can I directly pass the value of the async call into the price field in the lines where items are being pushed onto the return array? 
I have already tried setting price to the .done Promise return value:

price : that.getPriceText(items[0].productid).done(function (b) { return b; })

however, in my WebApp, price is then still "undefined", I assume because the first promise returning all items finished and displays all results.
This is actually what I want: display all product details, and then asynchronously retrieve the price.
Can anyone suggest the best method to achieve this?

Thanks!